# Group_by two columns and sum within R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset, data, with the following values:

```
               ID                TIME                         Duration   
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec                    
                B                12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM        7 sec
                B                12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM        0 sec
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        0 sec
```

I have 3 columns which consists of the ID, the TIME and the Duration. I wish to group by ID as well as Time and plot the Duration of the ID and Time using plotly.

```
               ID                TIME                         Duration   
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM       
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM                            
                B                12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM        7 sec
                B                12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM
```

As you can see here, the Duration is associated with the ID, and the Time column is also preserved.

I am trying a variation of this:

```
               aggregate(Duration ~ ID ~ TIME, df, FUN = sum)
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: `aggregate` returns the summarised output.  You may needd to create a column here with `ave` i.e. `df$New <- with(df, ave(Duration, ID, FUN = sum))`. The 'TIME' values all diffferent, so if you add `TIME` as grouping variable, it returns just the value because the length is 1 for each group

Comment: @akrun ok. Will this preserve the Time column?

Comment: Yes, because we are creating a new column

Comment: What type of data is in those columns? The output of `dput` would be more helpful since it will preserve data types

Comment: ok I will update. Thank you.

Comment: @akrun Ive been using this to filter dates in my dataset, is this correct? df1<-df %>%
                                       select(TIME)%>%
                                       filter(TIME >= "2019/09/09" & TIME =< "2019/09/09")

Comment: It may not work because the'TIME' needs to be converted. to `Date` or `Datetime' object with `as.POSIXct/as.Date`

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if the format/syntax is correct as well?

Comment: if wee use `lubridate` `df1$TIME <- as.Date(mdy_hms(df1$TIME))` and then you can do `df %>% filter(TIME >= as.Date("2019-09-09")|TIME <= as.Date("2019-09-09"))`

Comment: @akrun I did this, but the minutes and seconds disappear, and it is not filtering for just this date (I am still researching): library(lubridate)
dat1$TIME <- as.Date(mdy_hms(dat1$TIME))

dat2<-dat1 %>% filter(TIME >= as.Date("09-09-2019")|TIME <= as.Date("09-09-2019"))
View(dat2)

Comment: Just remove the `as.Date` and use only `mdy_hms(dat1$TIME)` because I thought you are comparing only 'Date' part

Comment: ok I did this library(lubridate)
dat1$TIME <- mdy_hms(dat1$TIME)

dat2<-dat1 %>% filter(TIME >= ("09-09-2019")| TIME <= ("09-09-2019"))   but its still not filtering the dataset to only 9/9/2019, it includes all the dates

Comment: `09-09-2019` is not correct Date class format, you may need `as.Date('2019-09-09')`

Comment: Ill try. Thank you

Comment: Could I do something like this: dat2<- dat1 %>% filter(as.Date(mdy_hms(TIME,format = 
                                         "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" )) == "2019-09-09" & 
                                  as.Date(mdy_hms(TIME, format = 
                                                    "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) == "2019-10-01")    Im still getting errors though. I wish to select a range of data within my dataset